# Where the "-no-boot-anim" command line switch comes from?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

**Context**

When I try to run my Android Xamarin project in Visual Studio 2017.3 the build is successful, then I am seeing that VS tries to start the emulator with the following command line:

C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -avd VisualStudio_android-23_arm_phone -prop monodroid.avdname=VisualStudio_android-23_arm_phone

Unfortunately the Emulator does nothing more than shows black screen. If I copy the command line and try to launch the very same command from the command prompt the issue is the same. However if I omit the **"-no-boot-anim"** switch the emulator starts OK.

**Now the question:**

How can I configure VS to omit this switch?

Comment: Why are you using a arm architecture emulator? Did you disable hyper-V of your computer?

Comment: I am using both, the question remains the same.

Comment: Probably the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46228480/how-do-i-remove-the-no-boot-anim-flag-from-emulator-startup