# How do I remove the `-no-boot-anim` flag from emulator startup?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using VS 15.4 preview 2 to test some things with Android 8.0. I am trying to launch (debug) my app into the AVD emulator but I just get a blank black screen in the emulator window after it opens.

[image]

I noticed that the command to open the emulator from VS output is:

```
2>Starting emulator AVD_Nexus_5_L26 ...
2>C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -avd AVD_Nexus_5_L26 -prop monodroid.avdname=AVD_Nexus_5_L26
2>Hax is enabled
2>Hax ram_size 0x80000000
2>HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
2>emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
2>emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
```

I try running the `emulator.EXE` command in the CMD prompt and I get the same problem.

After changing the command to (remove `-no-boot-anim` flag)

```
C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512 -avd AVD_Nexus_5_L26 -prop monodroid.avdname=AVD_Nexus_5_L26
```

the emulator start up fine from the CMD prompt.

Any idea how I can remove this flag from the emulator startup when trying to debug the app from within VS? Even when I try to open the emulator manually before debugging VS still closes it and opens a new instance with the `-no-boot-anim` flag.

Comment: In your `Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Settings` there is an "Additional Emulator Launch Arguments". However this is only additional arguments and thus there's not a way you can change this. Is there any reason why you would want to change this flag? This should help in every case given the documentation of: `Disable the boot animation during emulator startup for faster booting. On slower computers, this option can significantly speed up the boot sequence.` https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html Best thing you could do is file a bug.

Comment: "Is there any reason why you would want to change this flag?" Yes, please read the full question. I need to remove it for the emulator to be able to start.

Comment: My best guess is that this is an issue in your environment/AVD. Have you tested other machines/AVDs? My machine does not replicate this behavior. Removing `-no-boot-anim` adds additional time to the launch. What is your `config.ini` contents for this AVD?

Comment: And if Visual Studio is not recognizing that the AVD is already running and it starting a new instance of the "same" AVD, then I would say something is amiss in your configuration. Once the manually started one is running does it show up properly for `adb`? Is the Android SDK location in Visual Studio the one that you are getting your `emulator.exe` from? (I.e. do you have multiple versions of adb on your system)

Comment: I'm getting the same problem and found that it comes from -no-boot-anim too.
With the Google APIs Intel Atom API, the emulator stays black in all cases. With the Google Play Intel Atom ABI, it's black too unless I boot it from the command line without `-no-boot-anim`.
_"Use host GPU"_ option has no effect. Also, I have the same problem with VS restarting an already booted AVD (I encounter that bug since I know Xamarin, and it's been a while). But that's not always the case. And yes, VS uses the same SDK path as the rest of my system.